# How can I generate the latest for an aggregate?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hey stackoverflow community,

I have a table of `Sales`, hypothetical shown below.

```
Customer       Revenue       State      Date
David          $100          NY         2016-01-01
David          $500          NJ         2016-01-03
Fred           $200          CA         2016-01-01
Fred           $200          CA         2016-01-02
```

I'm writing a simple query of revenue generated by customer. The output returns as such:

```
David     $600
Fred      $400
```

What I want to do now is add the row for the latest purchase date.

Desired result:

```
David     $600      2016-01-03
Fred      $400      2016-01-02
```

I would like to keep the SQL code as clean as possible. I also want to avoid doing a JOIN to a new query as this query can start to get complex. Any ideas as to how to do so?

Comment: Look up top-n-per-group or greatest-n-per-group. For SQL Server see [Retrieving n rows per group‌​](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/86415/retrieving-n-rows-per-group).

Comment: Remember that you can accept an answer if it was helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You should sum revenues in your group and get the maximum of dates.

Something like this:

```
SELECT
  Customer, SUM(Revenue) as RevenueSum, MAX([Date]) as [Date]
FROM Sales
GROUP BY Customer
```

Comment: What if I wanted the latest state?

Comment: the latest state + latest date @Hamlet Hakobyan

Comment: @MichaelHwang: It is another question. Create question with appropriate title and description. You can add link of the new question that I can easily find it.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's what you need

**select Customer,sum(Revenue), max(Date) from Sales group by Customer**

Answer (score 0):

One way to get the SUM of Revenue and also get the information from the record with the MAX Date is to use the ROW_NUMBER() and SUM() windowed functions.

The `SUM() OVER()` will apply the sum for the Customer to each row and the `ROW_NUMBER() OVER()` will give each row an order number by Customer and Date DESC.

Put this in a subquery and select only the records with Row_Number of 1 (max date)

```
SELECT  [Customer],
        [Revenue],
        [State],
        [Date]
FROM    (SELECT [Customer],
                SUM([Revenue]) OVER (PARTITION BY [Customer]) [Revenue],
                [State],
                [Date],
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Customer] ORDER BY [Date] DESC) Rn
         FROM   Sales
        ) t
WHERE   t.Rn = 1
```